# Linking maps to dropdown menu in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, widget, panel, interaction

I am attempting to make an interactive app to display air quality data but am new to using panels and widgets so am running into some issues that I hope can be resolved.

First question:

Is there a way to display the layer drop down menu on both panels of the two panel map?

Right now I can only control the layers on the left hand side since that is the main map associated with the layer menu. I'd like to be able to toggle between layers between both panels.

Second question:

How do you link data to a drop down selection?

When a certain data type is selected on the left panel, I want the map to update with that data. Preferably, I'd like the left map to be 2019 data, right map to be 2020. I think it has something to do with 'onChange under ui.Select but can't figure it out.

Here is a link to my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/4d8c603ba6e7a015d74dd91e91c01630

Answer (score 1):

Here is a toy script that demonstrates the functionality you are looking for. This is just to help understand the mechanics - apply what you learn to your use case.

```js
// Make left and right maps.
var leftMap = ui.Map();
var rightMap = ui.Map();

// Make predefined data layers that can be selected.
var redImg = ui.Map.Layer(ee.Image.constant(1).visualize({palette: 'red'}));
var yellowImg = ui.Map.Layer(ee.Image.constant(1).visualize({palette: 'yellow'}));
var blueImg = ui.Map.Layer(ee.Image.constant(1).visualize({palette: 'blue'}));

// Add default layers to maps.
leftMap.add(redImg);
rightMap.add(blueImg);

// Link the maps
var linkedMaps = ui.Map.Linker([leftMap, rightMap]);

// Create a SplitPanel which holds the linked maps side-by-side.
var splitPanel = ui.SplitPanel({
  firstPanel: linkedMaps.get(0),
  secondPanel: linkedMaps.get(1),
  orientation: 'horizontal',
  wipe: true,
  style: {stretch: 'both'}
});

// Make a list of image layers to select from.
var layers = ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue'];

// Make a function that will retrieve a layer based on selection.
function getLayer(selection) {
  var layer = redImg;
  if(selection == 'Yellow') {
    layer = yellowImg;
  } else if(selection == 'Blue'){
    layer = blueImg;
  }
  return layer;
}

// Make a callback function for when a selection is made for left map.
function selectLeftOnChange(selection) {
  leftMap.layers().set(0, getLayer(selection));
}

// Make a callback function for when a selection is made for right map.
function selectRightOnChange(selection) {
  rightMap.layers().set(0, getLayer(selection));
}

// Define selection buttons for left and right map layers.
var selectLeft = ui.Select(layers, 'Red', 'Red', selectLeftOnChange, false, {position: 'top-left'});
var selectRight = ui.Select(layers, 'Blue', 'Blue', selectRightOnChange, false, {position: 'top-right'});

// Clear the root, add the splitPanel and buttons.
ui.root.clear();
ui.root.add(splitPanel);
leftMap.add(selectLeft);
rightMap.add(selectRight);
```

[Script link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6cb1e5eddcffb3bb90545ae4beb4102c)